# I can't get my Raspbery pi camera to change effects with if statements

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project for my computer science class. I've attached a camera and a distance sensor to my raspberry pi. the basic idea of the program is that that the pi will get a reading from the motion sensor and then depending on the reading it will take a picture with the camera and display a different camera effect and then keep updating the distance and the pictures on a loop.

My problem is that it will get stuck on the first camera effect that is activated, what I mean by this is if the distance sensor doesn't detect anything it will take a picture with no effect, if it picks up a closer reading it will display a negative, but if it doesn't detect anything initially it will continue to take pictures with no effect no matter what the reading actually is.

It also works the other way around as in if it detects something close it will continue to display a negative picture. I'm assuming what I did wrong has something to do with how I set up my loops.

```
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor
from time import sleep
ultrasonic = DistanceSensor(echo=17, trigger=4)
ultra = ultrasonic.distance
camera = PiCamera()
for x in range(5):
    print(ultrasonic.distance)
    sleep(2)
    while ultra == 1.0:
        camera.start_preview(alpha=192)
        sleep(5)
        camera.capture("/home/pi/final.jpg")
        camera.stop_preview()
        False 
    while ultra <= 0.05:
        camera.start_preview(alpha=192)
        camera.image_effect = 'negative'
        sleep(5)
        camera.capture("/home/pi/negativedistancefinal.jpg")
        camera.stop_preview()
        False
           
    while ultra >= 0.05:
        camera.start_preview(alpha=192)
        camera.image_effect = 'colorswap'
        sleep(5)
        camera.capture("/home/pi/colorswapdistancefinal.jpg")
        camera.stop_preview()
```

Comment: You're not updating the ultrasonic distance.  Your loops are all using the original captured version of `ultrasonic.distance`.  That's never going to change.  You need to read it again in every loop.  I assume you really want ``if` instead of `while` in those 3 placed.  ANd what do you think the `False` lines are doing?

Comment: Thank you so much Tim, I was very tired last night and accidentally submitted an edited version of my code where I sort of tried to brute force my way through it by trying various different loops, thank you for your patience

Comment: You're reading the distance from `ultrasonic.distance`, right?  That's reading from the distance sensor.  Your code reads that once, and uses that first value over and over.  Just move that line right after the `for` statement, just like HARSH MITTAL's answer below.

Comment: I've figured it out, by changing ultra to an input statement thank you so much to everyone who commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor
from time import sleep
ultrasonic = DistanceSensor(echo=17, trigger=4)

camera = PiCamera()
for x in range(5):
    ultra = ultrasonic.distance
    print(ultrasonic.distance)
    
    if ultra == 1.0:
        camera.start_preview(alpha=192)
        sleep(5)
        camera.capture("/home/pi/final.jpg")
        camera.stop_preview()
        
    elif ultra <= 0.05:
        camera.start_preview(alpha=192)
        camera.image_effect = 'negative'
        sleep(5)
        camera.capture("/home/pi/negativedistancefinal.jpg")
        camera.stop_preview()
        
           
    elif ultra >= 0.05:
        camera.start_preview(alpha=192)
        camera.image_effect = 'colorswap'
        sleep(5)
        camera.capture("/home/pi/colorswapdistancefinal.jpg")
        camera.stop_preview()
    sleep(2)
```

You need to update your readings and put if instead of while

Comment: You really should use "elif", because if "ultra" is 1.0, it's also going to trigger "ultra >= 0.05".